# 'C' binary executed through ProcessBuilder is blocking flow of execution

Tags: java, bufferedreader, processbuilder, bufferedwriter

I'm trying to execute a binary (written in 'C') through Java, while binary is executed successfully. It does not return execution control to this code (blocked) until 'Enter' keystroke is pressed. Because of this issue 'prcs.waitfor() == 0' is never executed and user don't know whether binary execution was successful or not. I tried to create BufferedWriter on OutputStream to send 'Enter' keystroke (//r) but it is not working. What needs to be done here so that execution control is back to this code and 'prcs.waitfor() ==0' is executed. I need to go ahead and execute another command which is dependent on successful execution of first command. I'm stuck with this :(

```
    // Start ProcessBuilder, 'str' contains a command

    ProcessBuilder pbuilder = new ProcessBuilder(str);
    pbuilder.directory(new File("/root/workspace/Project1"));
    pbuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process prcs = pbuilder.start();
    AForm.execStatustext.append("\n=> Process is:" + prcs);

    // Read output
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader bfrd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
    String current_line = null, previous_line = null;
    while ((current_line = bfrd.readLine()) != null) {
        if (!line.equals(previous_line)) {
            previous_line = current_line;
            out.append(current_line).append('\n');
            //System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
    //process.getInputStream().close();
    // Send 'Enter' keystroke through BufferedWriter to get control back
    BufferedWriter bfrout = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(prcs.getOutputStream()));
    bfrout.write("\\r");
    bfrout.newLine();
    bfrout.flush();
    bfrout.write("\\r");
    bfrout.newLine();
    bfrout.flush();
    //process.getOutputStream().close();*/

    if (prcs.waitFor() == 0)
        System.out.println("Commands executed successfully");
    System.exit(0);
```

Comment: There seems to be an error in your code BufferedReader bfrd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));. Shouldn't the "process" be "prcs"

Comment: @Ifthikhan Yes. It should be 'prcs' but that is just a typo. Issue of not able to execute 'Enter' through BufferedWriter still exists. Thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

`\\r` is not caret return, it's `\` followed by `r`. caret return is just `\r`

also, `bfrout.newLine();` should cover platform-dependent line separator. maybe you don't need caret return at all?

Comment: Thanks Denis for reply. I tried both things but it is still not taking '/r' OR bfrout.newLine() as 'Enter' keystroke. Flow of execution is stuck there at system call and hence (prcs.waitFor == 0) block is not getting executed.

Comment: UPDATE: One thing I noticed is that after I execute system call through processbuilder it takes 6 seconds to execute command and then returns a success message through InputStreamReader. Is it possible that because of this delay 'process.waitFor == 0' is not getting executed ? But I was thinking that after 6 seconds it should get executed anyways ?

Comment: @losmx: are you sure your code does not block at `bfrd.readLine()` waiting for new input?